# Core data performance issue

Tags: swift, performance, core-data, macos-sierra

I have a core data model contains three entities (without inheritance).

```
Management
Team Leader
worker
```

The relationship between the entities:
For under any manager can be more managers, team leaders and workers.
For under any team manager can be other workers.

The model is contained in total more than 100,000 objects.

All the data represent by NSOutlineView, for example:

```
*Management
 -Management
   -Management
     -Team Leader
       -worker
       -worker
       -worker
   -Management
       -worker
       -worker
   -Management
   -worker
   -worker
   -worker
*Management
     -Team Leader
       -worker
       -worker
     -Team Leader
*Management
     -Team Leader
       -worker
       -worker
```

The user can filter the outline view by typing text (tokens) on a text field.

For each group of tokens, I search in the core data model if the entity or any relationship entities contain all the tokens and if the answer is true, the entity will represent in the outline view, and all his ancestors, for example if only two workers contain all the tokens, the user will see (for both of the workes, the nearest common ancestor is the third manager, and for the first worker there is team leader also):

```
Management
 -Management
   -Management
     -Team Leader
       -<worker>
     -<worker>
```

So, basically my data structure is a tree, and the most intuitive way (for me) to search is recursive algorithm (I've done it with DFS).

(If I understand correctly, there is no way to search recursively with NSPredicate.)

So, for each group of tokens (I use throttling in order to avoid redundancies
 search while the user is typing). I passe through the top managers (The managers on the top) and through all their relationship entities (sub management, Team leadera and workers).

This search operation takes a long time.
IMHO the main problem is that I pass through all the entities all the time, and I cannot improve the performance with indexing that becouse I don't use query, I just go through each all the objects and load them to the memory, and I also experience the performance issue mainly in earlier queries, before the objects on the memory.

Any advice how to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

why you search recursive?

i would do it in this way:

- just search in all 3 entities one per time with NSPredicate:

  - you get 3 results.
- from this three result build your result tree:

  - for each hit append also the breadcrumps up to the root to the result tree